# System of non-linear ODE's

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, systems-of-equations

do you have any suggestions to solve analytically the Non-linear ODE system

$\dot x=18 x^2 y-3p x^2+6p xy$

$\dot y=18 x^2 y-6p xy $

where $p$ is a real constant.

Thank you very much

cheers

Comment: I don't know what this could do, but you can eliminate $y$ from the first equation and plug into the second. This would give you a second order differential equation in $x$. Solve it (if it works) and get $y$ from the initial definition.

Comment: What have you considered? Even if what you considered or tried didn't get you where you want to go, it helps us know how best to hone in and help you.

Comment: By "analytically", you mean to find closed form expressions for $x(t)$ and $y(t)$?  Mathematica is unable to find such expressions and I see no reason to think that such expressions exist.  On the other hand, you can "analytically" find that the origin and $(p/3,p/12)$ are equilibria, use linear algebra to classify the behavior at those points, and finally see how these fit into the vector field determined by the system.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thanks, I tried that but the resulting equation for x is also quite involved, I will have a look at it again.

Comment: @MarkMcClure Yes, I mean a closed expression. Mathematica cannot find any solution indeed but I was hoping that there is some trick that can do the job. I've done the linearized analysis and indeed the fixed points are those ones.  Thanks

Comment: I'd suggest starting from $dy/dx=P(x,y;c)$; by finding an appropriate integrating factor, you should be able to get an implicit function $F(x,y;c)=$const. Plotting this for various $c$ should give you a sense of what the solutions are doing (albeit while saying nothing about the _rate_ at which they're doing it).

Answer (score 0):

There are no explicit solutions for most of the nonlinear systems. Therefore, they are linearized near the fixed points. The eigenvalues near the fixed points mostly give idea about the phase portrait solutions of such systems. For this system fixed points are $(0,0)$ and $(p/3,p/12)$. The eigenvalues near the $(p/3,p/12)$ are:

$\lambda_{1,2}=\frac{-p^{2}}{4}\mp\frac{p^{2}}{2}\sqrt{\frac{31}{4}}i$

which means this is an asymptothycally stable spiral point.

**However**, the eigenvalues near the origin are found to be zero. This means linearization does not describe the system. Therefore, I don't think you can find an easy solution for this system even when the linearization does not work.

Answer (score -2):

Solutions to these types of  equations .....(dx/dt) =F1(x,y.z) ;(dy/dt) =F2(x,y,z);(dz/dt) =F3(x,y,z) , ....which are called State Space Equations , are found in Non-linear Control System Engg. and Advanced Control System Engg. books.